# libssl.so.5 required for xmlsec1-openssl on Amazon AMI Linux

Tags: amazon-ec2, openssl

I am trying to set up xmlsec1-openssl in order to install LASSO on an Amazon AMI Linux. I have xmlsec1 1.2.7-4 setup for an x84_64 arch. I downloaded the RPM for the xmlsec1-openssl 1.2.7-4 (x86_64) from [here](ftp://ftp-stud.fht-esslingen.de/pub/Mirrors/download.fedoralegacy.org/fedora/4/os/x86_64/xmlsec1-openssl-1.2.7-4.x86_64.rpm)

When I execute `yum install openssl-1.2.7-4.x86_64.rpm` , I get an error stating that libcrypto.so.5 and libssl.so.5 are required and are missing. I have checked in the /usr/lib directory and see libssl.so.10 and libcrypto.so.10 in there. Is this an openssl issue? What can I do now so I can install the package.

Comment: That RPM is not meant for Amazon Linux. It's also many years old.

Comment: What can I do to set it up on Amazon Linux? Any repository from which the package might be available?

Comment: First, exactly which "LASSO" are you trying to install? Unfortunately there are apparently several projects with this name.

Comment: trying to install v2.2 of the Liberty Alliance SSO(LASSO) http://lasso.entrouvert.org/

Comment: Then you have two questions: Why an old version? And why not use a Linux distribution that already includes it, such as Fedora?

Comment: 1) Was trying to configure xmlsec1 and xmlsec1-openssl. I have xmlsec1 setup but the 2.5 version is not recognizing xmlsec1 when I try to compile it from source
2) I have an Amazon AMI machine and I have a lot set up on it and can't change as of now.